# how to stop a child div when scrolling to it and make internal scroll with animation using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create an webpage with the functionality of scrolling child div with animation,
here is an [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xV5mzW8NbXPqqPd_cxTIrY498gmQBJ2W/view?usp=sharing).

I have tried with on scroll in JavaScript but not working.
Currently i have created this same on click of these cards.
But i want this on scroll of that div.

this example is just a one module in my website, after this div and before this div there are so many content, So basically this example module is in center of the website.

Tried code 1:
js code

```
function scrollFunc() {
  alert("is this working properly?");
  document.getElementById("platform-cards").style.backgroundColor = "black"
  document.getElementById("cards-main-div").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("card-info-div").style.display = "block"
}
```

html code

```
<div class="cards" onscroll="scrollFunc()">
</div>
```

Tried code 2:
js code

```
const cardMainDiv = document.querySelector('.cards-main-div');
cardMainDiv.addEventListener('scroll',(e)=> {
alert("it is working....")
// EVEN ALERT IS NOT WORKING
  document.getElementById("platform-cards").style.backgroundColor = "black"
  document.getElementById("cards-main-div").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("card-info-div").style.display = "block"
});
```

html code

```
<div class="cards">
</div>
<div class="card-info-div" id="card-info-div">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the codes you tried so far

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help with inserting code.

Comment: i have updated the code and also consider i don't know how to code so tell me from scratch.

Comment: Your HTML seems incorrect is that just a copy&paste error in the example code? `<div> class="cards" onscroll="scrollFunc()"` should be this instead: `<div class="cards" onscroll="scrollFunc()">

Comment: @PeterKrebs it was just a typing mistake in stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code, what you want to achieve. Hope it will be helpful.

```js
const scrollDiv = document.querySelector('.scrollDiv');
    scrollDiv.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=>{
      // Do whatever on scroll
      // I am just changing the background color of div
      const target = e.currentTarget;
      target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
```

```css
 body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    h1,
    p {
      margin: 2rem 1rem;
    }

    .scrollDiv {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="scrollDiv">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Recusandae, autem ut doloribus inventore odit temporibus
      eaque voluptas laboriosam, tempora quia optio a enim accusamus nostrum repellat maxime accusantium asperiores. Ex
      voluptatem sequi aut autem laborum temporibus. Sit obcaecati inventore illum molestias quo vero at, necessitatibus
      dolores a doloremque accusamus eum.
    </div>
    <p>What are you doing?</p>
  </div>
```

It will fire the event only on the internal div scroll.

Comment: I have tried this as well but this is also not working.

Comment: why not working? The scroll event is firing on internal div. Then what's you want to acheive?

Comment: I do not know why it is not working, but i have tried the same with different combinations as well.

Comment: Share your code, on question. Let me seee